# WPF Designer Code keeps telling me that there are errors

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

Here is my Form XAML code.

```
<Window x:Class="Bail.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns="clr-namespace:Bail"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="768" Width="1024" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Closing="Window_Closing" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources> 
            <src:ListboxMenuItems x:Key="ListboxMenuItems"/>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="185" />
            <!-- Or Auto -->
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


        <ListBox Width="150" Margin="0,5,0,10" Grid.Column="0"
                 ItemsSource="{StaticResource ListboxMenuItems}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Padding="5,0,5,0" Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" />
                        <TextBlock Text=", " />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Address}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>            
        </ListBox>


        <Canvas Grid.Column="1" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here are the errors

---

after correcting the xmlns:src, I get the following
Warning:

### Warning 1   ''src' is an undeclared prefix. Line 8, position 14.' XML is not valid. C:\Users\Shayaan Siddiqui\Documents\Bail\Bail\Bail\MainWindow.xaml  8   14  Bail

ListBoxMenuItems is a class I created in C#.

Here;s the code to the class

```
//FileName: ListboxMenuItems.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Bail
{
    public class ListboxMenuItem
    {
        public String FirstName { get; set; }
        public String LastName { get; set; }
        public String Address { get; set; }

        public ListboxMenuItem(String firstName, String lastName, String address)
        {
            this.FirstName = firstName;
            this.LastName = lastName;
            this.Address = address;
        }
    }

    class ListboxMenuItems 
    { 
        List<ListboxMenuItem> Items { get; private set; } 
        public ListboxMenuItems() 
        { 
            Items = new List<ListboxMenuItem>(); 
            Items.Add(new ListboxMenuItem("Michael", "Anderberg", "12 North Third Street, Apartment 45")); 
            Items.Add(new ListboxMenuItem("Chris", "Ashton", "34 West Fifth Street, Apartment 67")); 
            Items.Add(new ListboxMenuItem("Cassie", "Hicks", "56 East Seventh Street, Apartment 89")); 
            Items.Add(new ListboxMenuItem("Guido", "Pica", "78 South Ninth Street, Apartment 10")); 
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: It would be most helpful if you provided the error as well =D

Comment: posted errors and updated code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a namespace declaration in the `Window` tag:

```
<window x:Class="Bail.MainWindow" 
        xmlns:src="clr-namespace:Bail" 
        .../>
```

Also, if you've changed the names of the objects to remove the "s" at the end, you will need to change that in the xaml as  well.

```
<Grid.Resources> 
    <src:ListboxMenuItem x:Key="ListboxMenuItems"/> 
</Grid.Resources>
```

Comment: The issue is that intellisense won't suggest src. I added the name of the project to the xmlns but the form designer has the same issue. If you need to see any more code, let me know

Comment: @Cocoa Dev, you forgot to add the "src" to the `xmlns:src="clr-namespace:Bail"`declaration. I've updated my answer so you can copy/paste the line into your code.

Comment: Very weird that error is gone. Without the `src` in the `xmlns` declaration, it won't know what `<src:ListboxMenuItem .../>` is in your `<Grid.Resources>` tag. After adding `src` to the `xmlns` declaration you should also see intellisense later in the xaml.

Answer (score 3):

xmlns:src="clr-namespace:ListBoxSnippetEx"

This line is missing in your code. Replace ListBoxSnippetEx with your project namespace.

Answer (score 2):

You've also got an extra < character line 8:

```
    <Grid.Resources> 
        < 
        <src:ListboxMenuItems x:Key="ListboxMenuItems"/>
```

Comment: Good observation but that only appears in this post. It must be a copy/paste error. That extra < doesn't appear in my code.